# c# string that has to contain quote "

Tags: c#, regex, quote

```
string aniPattern=@"(?si:<option value=\\\"(?<year>.*?)\\)";
```

This breakes because the " in the middle. But I need that because I use it in a regex.

I tried to use `string aniPattern="(?si:<option value=\\\"(?<year>.*?)\\\\)";`(without @) but it isnot a valid regex.

Answer (score 12):

**important** - it isn't entirely clear what you want to match; I've answered on the premise that **only** the `"` is being a problem - but see also [Mike Caron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493353/c-string-that-has-to-contain-quote/4493382#4493382) which assumes *everything* is escaped incorrectly.

With a verbatim string literal (i.e. `@"..."`), `"` is escaped to `""` - so your string becomes:

```
string aniPattern=@"(?si:<option value=\\\""(?<year>.*?)\\)";
```

With a *regular* string literal (without the leading `@`), you would need a lot worse:

```
string aniPattern="(?si:<option value=\\\\\\\"(?<year>.*?)\\\\)";
```

Comment: I have a feeling that the slashes before the quote are specifically for dealing with the quote. I suspect he wants to match something like `<option value="1995"`

Comment: @Mike - I've clarified what *this* post addresses, pointing to your answer too. It is my suspicion that yours is indeed closer.

Comment: Also, I wonder what the final slash is for? I suspect that is an error too, but I left it in since I'm not sure... I guess the OP will have to clarify.

Answer (score 8):

```
string aniPattern=@"(?si:<option value=""(?<year>.*?)\)";
```

For @ escaped strings, you double the quotation mark to escape it, since backslash is not used.

Answer (score 2):

Use two double quotes next to each other, like so: `""`